# How can I compare 2 arrays and perform multiple actions based on differences?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have a list of items that is stored in a DB, and I want to provide functionality for editing this list.  I want users to be able to add and remove items from this list as much as they want, and then only hit some sort of "save" button once, when they are finished editing.  I then need to update the list in the DB with these changes.  How can I do this without having to remove this list from the DB, and re-adding it?

EX:
Original List: item a, item b, item c
New List: item a, item c, item d, item e

I have looked at the array_diff() function, but I don't think it will give me what I need, as I need information from both arrays.

Comment: array_diff, array_diff_key, array_intersect, array_intersect_key ......  all of these output things diffrent if you change the order, `array_diff($arr1, $arr2)` and `array_diff($arr2, $arr1)`  unless they are the same array that is.  Also useful is array_merge, and array_replace.

Comment: What have you tried already? Perhaps play around with all the different array functions available and see if any work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Array diff will give you the difference between the first array and all the other arrays.  You can change up what is the first array.  The difference will be all elements not present in the other arrays.  If you want to compare by keys, and not values, use array_diff_key.

Array Intersect will give the items that intersect or are the same, so basically all items from array 1 that appear in the other arguments.  Again, you can change what is the first array.

Array merge, will combine 2 arrays, overwriting if they have string keys, the original array would be array1 and then anything after will overwrite in the order they appear left to right.  They will not overwrite numbered indexes but instead add elements.

Array Replace is just like merge, except when it comes to numbered indexes.

There is also recursive merge and replace.

With these you can tell a lot about the arrays for example.

```
  $arr1 = ['one'=>'foo','two'=>bar'];
  $arr2 = ['one' => 'foo', 'three' => 'blue'];

$a = array_diff_key( $arr1, $arr2 );
$b = array_diff_key( $arr2, $arr1 );
```

So  (without actually testing this ) `$a` should be

```
 array('two'=>'bar');
```

Because that element is not present in the second array

and `$b` is

```
 array( 'three' => 'blue' );
```

Because ( again ) that element is not present in the second array

Using intersect we could tell that `one=>` appears in both arrays.  Not sure if that helps but that is how they work, I use them all the time.

Answer (score 0):

`array_diff` should work, but you will need to use it twice to get the information you need in order to avoid removing and re-adding the entire list. Without writing all the queries and whatnot, here is the general approach I would use:

```
$db_list = $pdo->query('SELECT item FROM your_db.your_list')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user_list = $_POST['list_items_entered_by_user'];

// Gets items in user list, but not in db
$inserts = array_diff($user_list, $db_list);

// Gets items in db, but not in user list
$deletes = array_diff($db_list, $user_list);

// start transaction
// DELETE $deletes
// INSERT $inserts
// commit transaction
```